# Save Image metadata PHPhotoLibrary vs ALAssetsLibrary

Tags: ios10, alassetslibrary, cgimage, phasset, phphotolibrary

When using ALAssetsLibrary, I used to save image to photo library with proper exif using the code below:

```
        NSInteger orientation = 2;// Or whatever
        NSData *jpegData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageDataSampleBuffer];

CMSetAttachment(imageDataSampleBuffer, kCGImagePropertyOrientation,
                [NSNumber numberWithInt: orientation],
                kCMAttachmentMode_ShouldPropagate);

    ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

    CFDictionaryRef attachments = CMCopyDictionaryOfAttachments(kCFAllocatorDefault, imageDataSampleBuffer, kCMAttachmentMode_ShouldPropagate);

    [library writeImageDataToSavedPhotosAlbum:jpegData metadata:(id)attachments completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {
          ...
          ...
     }
```

It's not clear how to translate that code when using PHPhotoLibrary. Can anyone provide the right way to save attachments along with the jpeg image?

Answer (score 0):

Use ImageIO to add Metadata to your JPEG/PNG image as described in the following article:
[Save the exif metadata using the new PHPhotoLibrary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35758510/save-the-exif-metadata-using-the-new-phphotolibrary/35977202#35977202)